# How many ways can n identical rings be interconnected (in 3 dimensions)?

Tags: combinatorics, knot-theory, combinatorial-geometry

I am thinking of two configurations of rings as being equivalent if you can physically move them from one configuration to the other without deforming the rings or have them intersect each-other.

If you think of each ring as a node on a graph and the linking of two rings as edges of a graph then this problem becomes how many graphs of order n are there. Or maybe I am missing something, like if ring C can go through rings A and B in multiple ways ...

The only issue I can see is if there is some graph for which there does not correspond an allowable ( edges of rings get in the way somehow) configuration of rings. I know this is the difficulty for calculating the number of possible Venmo diagrams (n=6 isn’t even known!) but not sure if the same issue arises with this problem.

Comment: If you have a chain of rings, closed into a loop, this corresponds to a cycle graph. You can add twists before closing the loop, like a mobius strip. This leads to configurations that are not equivalent to each other, though these twists are of course not captured in the graph representation.

Comment: And of course a looped chain like that can be knotted or not. The question of whether a graph can be impossible to realise is interesting, and I don't know of an example. All complete graphs are possible. Hardest may be a complete graph with a few edges removed.

Comment: Good point about creating knots!  I have some intuition that some configuration will not be possible ... with a lot of connectedness for large n, the rings will be clumped up with little freedom of movement possible. Now if we add more one ring, we have to be able to do it in  2^n ways in order for no counter example to exist (one for every combination of the previous n rings). Seems like a lot to ask... but I'm not sure - I go back and forth. Should I change the question to "Can n identical rings be interconnected arbitrarily? "

Comment: In the 3-sphere (a common setting for knot theory), these are called *great circle links*.  From the point of view of a stereographic projection to $\mathbb{R}^3$, they're links where each component is a geometric circle whose radius is the reciprocal of its minimal distance to the origin, I think.  There's a classification for up to five rings by Genevieve Walsh: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0308048 (though I don't remember if it's using the more restrictive notion of equivalence).

Comment: [Here's an arrangement](https://twitter.com/KangarooPhysics/status/1457123532849270787?s=20) that can almost, but not quite, be realized by four identical rings, to give an example of something that seems not to violate any rules (everything links through everything else at most once), but still the situation is too constrained to be possible.

Comment: I disagree that this would be a counter example - they just arranged them stupidly. If you were to lay them (almost) flat it would work. Like @JaapScherphuis said, complete graphs (and their associated intersecting rings) are easy.

Comment: I'm confused, are these rings supposed to be rigid geometric circles? I don't see how they could possibly be flattened without changing the topological type of the link. You can make the "interlinking graph" be a complete graph by using a (4,4) torus link, but that's not equivalent.

Comment: I mean orient them on a flat surface, not change their topology.  Here is how you would do it with 3 rings <https://www.fhinds.co.uk/wedding-rings/ladies-wedding-rings/9ct-Rose-Gold-Russian-Wedding-Ring-2mm-R17543>. I hope you can see that rings could be added indefinitely.

Comment: You can indeed keep adding rings (if they are thin enough), letting each new ring go through the central hole of the pile and then laying it as flat as possible in the pile itself. A nicer visualisation is to trace out circles on the surface of a torus that go around and through the torus hole, and when n circles are equally spaced around the torus this arrangement has a beautiful symmetry to it. [Villarceau circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Villarceau_circles)

Comment: @JaapScherphuis For n rings, that's an (n,n) torus link you're describing (in fancy terminology, it's a link made from fibers of the Hopf fibration).  The 4 almost-ring arrangement I mentioned earlier is a link called L12a2007, which is not equivalent to any of these torus links.  [Here's a flattened version of the diagram](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FDdf6z-VcAAt1DW?format=png&name=small), though with no attempt to make the circles round.

Comment: @KyleMiller Right, just like a set Borromean rings is not equivalent to unlinked rings. I assumed that for now we were ignoring the twist, orientation, knottedness etc and just focussing on whether there was any connection graph that was not realisable by rigid linked circles.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis You could ask the same question if the circles are in 2 dimensional space, and they are "connected" if they intersect. That seems more tractable ...