# Can identical rings intersect in any combinations in 3d space?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, combinatorial-geometry

For every undirected graph G, with nodes $a_1,...,a_n$. Can we find n circles/rings of fixed radius, $c_1,...,c_n$ in 3 dimensions such that there exists an edge between $a_i$ and $a_j$ if and only if $c_i$ and $c_j$ are linked.

This is a simpler version of this question
[How many ways can n identical rings be interconnected (in 3 dimensions)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4320878/how-many-ways-can-n-identical-rings-be-interconnected-in-3-dimensions)
In the discussion it quickly became clear that with the ability to make knots and things like the mobius strip makes the problem too difficult. A complete graph is doable by Villarceau circles.

Comment: I don't see how this could work. You cannot put circles in the plane as you put lines. Imagine a graph with a center node from which plenty of edges exit. In your proposition you should put many circles that intersect a central one. They will surely intersect more than you wish. In fact you have a counter example right away: one central node which connects to seven outer nodes which are not connected.

Comment: @BeniBogosel Good point! Perhaps more interesting if we place the rings in a 3 dimensions....

Comment: Every graph on $4$ or fewer vertices can be realized as a circle configuration where all circles are within any $\epsilon>0$ of a given circle (this isn't too hard to convince yourself of by hand). This means that a minimal counterexample must not have any collection of $1$ to $4$ vertices whose connections to the other vertices are identical, or else one could take a solution of the graph given by condensing those vertices and "enlarge" the target vertex by adding epsilon-perturbed rings next to the target ring to create the desired graph.

Comment: This, combined with a few manual checks for simple things like the ability to add a vertex of degree 1 to a solution, makes it pretty easy to check that every graph on up to $5$ vertices is realizable - for the $6$-vertex case, it should at least reduce the number of undetermined graphs to some fairly tractable collection.

Comment: What does "$c_i$ and $c_j$ are linked" mean exactly?  Does it mean the rings touch each other (= share a point), or that each passes through the interior of the other, or either?